# Unity test ads suddenly stopped working in builds but works in editor without any errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

So I implemented Unity ads into my android game a few days ago and it worked like intended up until now. It suddenly stopped showing test ads on android builds but still works just as it did before in the editor. No code has been changed that could interfere with it.

So i've tried to change the code and turning on and off the ad service but nothing has helped. The only thing i can think of at the moment is an error I had that only showed up once. I'm not sure but I think it was something about Player Settings. Didn't think more of it since nothing happened after it.

```
       if(ad >= 16)
        {
            if (Advertisement.IsReady("video"))
            {
                Advertisement.Show("video");
                ad = 0;
            }
        }
```

I don't think it has something to do with the code since it worked before and still is working in the editor. I haven't published the app yet so I don't know if the real ads will show or not.

UnityAdsEditor: Initialize(xxxxxxx, True);
UnityEditor.Advertisements.UnityAdsEditor:EditorOnLoad()